# Apache Spark - Dataset operations fail in abstract base class?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, abstract-class

I'm trying to extract some common code into an abstract class, but running into issues.

Let's say I'm reading in a file formatted as "id|name":

```
case class Person(id: Int, name: String) extends Serializable

object Persons {
  def apply(lines: Dataset[String]): Dataset[Person] = {
    import lines.sparkSession.implicits._
    lines.map(line => {
      val fields = line.split("\\|")
      Person(fields(0).toInt, fields(1))
    })
  }
}

Persons(spark.read.textFile("persons.txt")).show()
```

Great. This works fine.  Now let's say I want to read a number of different files with "name" fields, so I'll extract out all of the common logic:

```
trait Named extends Serializable { val name: String }

abstract class NamedDataset[T <: Named] {
  def createRecord(fields: Array[String]): T
  def apply(lines: Dataset[String]): Dataset[T] = {
    import lines.sparkSession.implicits._
    lines.map(line => createRecord(line.split("\\|")))
  }
}

case class Person(id: Int, name: String) extends Named

object Persons extends NamedDataset[Person] {
  override def createRecord(fields: Array[String]) =
    Person(fields(0).toInt, fields(1))
}
```

This fails with two errors:

```
Error:
Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  
Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) 
are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing 
other types will be added in future releases.
lines.map(line => createRecord(line.split("\\|")))

Error:
not enough arguments for method map: 
(implicit evidence$7: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[T])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T].
Unspecified value parameter evidence$7.
lines.map(line => createRecord(line.split("\\|")))
```

I have a feeling this has something to do with implicits, TypeTags, and/or ClassTags, but I'm just starting out with Scala and don't fully understand these concepts yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to make two small changes:

- Since only primitives and `Product`s are supported (as error message states), making your `Named` trait `Serializable` isn't enough. You should make it extend `Product` (which means case classes and Tuples can extend it)
- Indeed both `ClassTag` and `TypeTag` are required for Spark to overcome type erasure and figure out the actual types

So - here's a working version:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

trait Named extends Product { val name: String }

abstract class NamedDataset[T <: Named : ClassTag : TypeTag] extends Serializable {
  def createRecord(fields: Array[String]): T
  def apply(lines: Dataset[String]): Dataset[T] = {
    import lines.sparkSession.implicits._
    lines.map(line => createRecord(line.split("\\|")))
  }
}

case class Person(id: Int, name: String) extends Named

object Persons extends NamedDataset[Person] {
  override def createRecord(fields: Array[String]) =
    Person(fields(0).toInt, fields(1))
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Good to know I was at least on the right track.